# Unreachable Code Detected Warning

Tags: c#, warnings, unreachable-code

Alright, so I've been trying to fix this for a good while now. I have a "warning" within my code - "Unreachable Code Detected". I'm not sure how to fix this, which is why I'm posting here. Below is the code:

```
    public static byte Authenticate(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `AccountID` = '" + UserName + "'", Connection);
            DataSet DSet = new DataSet();

            DataAdapter.Fill(DSet, "Account");

            if (DSet != null && DSet.Tables["Account"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow DR = DSet.Tables["Account"].Rows[0];

                string Pass = (string)DR["Password"];
                if (Pass == Password || Pass == "")
                {
                    if (Pass == "")
                    {
                        MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `Accounts` SET `Password` = '" + Password + "' WHERE `AccountID` = '" + UserName + "'", Connection);
                        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    uint LogonCount = (uint)DR["LogonCount"];
                    LogonCount++;

                    MySqlCommand Comm = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `Accounts` SET `LogonCount` = " + LogonCount + " WHERE `AccountID` = '" + UserName + "'", Connection);
                    Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return Convert.ToByte((uint)DR["LogonType"]);
                }
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }

        catch (Exception Exc) { General.WriteLine(Exc.ToString()); return 0; General.ServerRestart(); }
    }
```

I don't know how to highlight it red, so I'll post the specific line:

```
    catch (Exception Exc) { General.WriteLine(Exc.ToString()); return 0; General.ServerRestart(); }
```

The warning is "General".ServerRestart();

Comment: When you hit `return 0;` at your highlighted line of code, do you naturally expect the statement that follows to execute? Because you shouldn't. Neither does the compiler. Ergo, it is marked as unreachable.

Answer (score 4):

General.ServerRestart() must happen before you call return. Return immediately exits the method before any remaining code is not ran, hence the warning for "unreachable code"

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (Exception Exc)
{
    General.WriteLine(Exc.ToString());
    return 0;
    General.ServerRestart();
}
```

In your catch block, you are returning a value and then performing extra functions.

When you write "return 0;", it doesn't "set" the return value to be 0 when the function completes, but it returns the value 0 as the result of the function and stops the function at that point.
So when you have a return statement, any code afterwards will never be executed, because the function will terminate before that, at the return statement.

Note this scenario:

```
// ... some code 1

if (someExpression)
{
    // ... some code 2

    return;

    // ... some code 3
}

// ... some code 4

return;

// ... some code 5
```

The code1 will always execute. If someExpression is true - code2 will execute (and others won't), otherwise - code 4 will execute (and others won't).
In any case, code3 and code5 won't execute, because in each of their perspective code paths, they come after a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning prematurely. Statements following a return will not be executed as they are "Unreachable".

Answer (score 1):

```
    catch (Exception Exc) { General.WriteLine(Exc.ToString()); return 0; General.ServerRestart(); }
```

should be:

```
    catch (Exception Exc) { General.WriteLine(Exc.ToString()); General.ServerRestart(); return 0; }
```

You can't call General.ServerRestart after you've just exited the function.

Answer (score 0):

when you return something, it ends the method. Its not possible to return multiple values, unless its a list. and even lists would be returned in one line like `return ListName;`

Comment: So should I switch them around like this?:

        catch (Exception Exc) { General.WriteLine(Exc.ToString()); General.ServerRestart(); return 0; }

Comment: "It's not possible to return multiple values"...?  Someone hasn't heard about generators (pardon me...'enumerators').  :)